# How to get ID of currently logged in user using spring security and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Spring security in my project and Thymeleaf view. I am trying to get ID of currently logged user so I can use it for some of my method.

For example I am trying to add user to one class. In html part I have button like this.

```
<td th:each="user : ${user}">
    <a th:href="@{/userList/{user_id}/saveClasses/{classes_id} (user_id=${user.id}, classes_id=${classes.id})}">Attend</a>
</td>
```

When I run my code I get 2 Attend buttons for 2 of my users that I have in database.
I would like to have one button for user that of course is currently logged in. How can I do that?

For displaying username of logged user I am using this:

```
<span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello <span sec:authentication="name"></span></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

---

After spending couple of hours trying to find answer finally found solution that works for me.

I have done it using repository, this is my implementation:

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserDetailsService {

     public User findUserByUsername(String username);

}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl**

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
 private UserRepository userRepository;

 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
  return userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
 }
```

}

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/dashboardUser")
    public String dashboardPageList(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails currentUser ) {
    User user = (User) userRepository.findUserByUsername(currentUser.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("currentStudent", user);

        return "dashboardUser";
    }
```

and in .html file I displayed it like this

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label>Username</label> 
    <input type="text" name="username" 
    th:value="${currentStudent.username}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand under `${user}` you have list of users from your database.
I see here two options.

1. You can add to `Model` currently logged in user in your controller:

   ```
   public String foo(Model model) {
       User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
       String username = user.getUsername();
       model.addAttribute("username", username);
       return "your_view";
   }
   ```

   and then in your html:

   ```
   <td th:each="user : ${user}">
       <a th:if="${username == user.username}" th:href="@{/userList/{user_id}/saveClasses/{classes_id} (user_id=${user.id}, classes_id=${classes.id})}">Attend</a>
   </td>
   ```
2. In your `th:each` you can add `th:if` to check that `user` is currently logged in. Here is few ways too. One of them is:

   ```
   <td th:each="user : ${user}">
       <a th:if="${#authentication.getName() == user.username}" th:href="@{/userList/{user_id}/saveClasses/{classes_id} (user_id=${user.id}, classes_id=${classes.id})}">Attend</a>
   </td>
   ```
3. If you have database you have probably models - [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database) you can find detailed description how to do it with your custom class for user. 1 and 2 option are the easiest in your case but this one is more elegant.

In my solutions users from database need field `username`.
Also I recommend to hold list of users in variable called `users` instead od `user`- it's more readable.

Comment: With this first option how am I getting ID of currently logged user? What I can see i get username and that is it. I have already achieve that. Also in second option will I get ID? With `th:each="user : ${user}"` I will again have number of Attend buttons in row as I have users stored in database. And I want only from currently logged user. @Nequeq

Comment: I added it but I got this error: `ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.oggi.model.User` do you know why?

Comment: Ok, I have made a mistake. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` returns `User` class which implements `interface UserDetails` - [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html).
Your class has to implement this interface and then you should be able cast it to `UserDetails` instead of `User`. Try this and let me know.

Comment: I have a question this method is inside of my controller. I updated my question again to show hoe it looks like. When I implement in it UserDetails with this line of code `long id = user.getId();` I can't get ID I can only get Authorities(), class(), password() and username(). @Nequeq

Comment: [Here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/122998-how-to-use-custom-userdetails-in-spring-security) you have full example.

Comment: I have question I have implemented like everything on link you send me, update is in my answer. But how do I retrieve only ID? @Nequeq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152271/discussion-between-nequeq-and-dome).

Comment: Hi @Nequeq  I found solution, you can check my code in answer below yours. This is what have worked for me. Will appreciate all inputs. :)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! your solution was very helpful for me. Worked like a charm!